# How to fully delete a virus

Tags: windows-7, virus, anti-virus, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

I caught a virus earlier this week.  Rebooted to safe mode w/ networking and ran a scan for all .exe and .dll files that changed recently. Found one such file (`jfketcl.exe`), and scanned it with VirusTotal which detected it as Malware (interestingly enough, MBAM didn't catch it!).

I want to delete this, but not sure what is the surest way. I am currently in Safe Mode, which, if I understand Safe Mode correctly, means it can't execute without me manually invoking it (**correct?**).

I figure I should delete the file **and** empty the Recycle Bin. But something tells me there's more to it than that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Adam - this is the second question you've asked that's been closed as a duplicate of our master 'here's how you fix malware' question.  The answers over there really should tell you anything you need to know - is there something specific that you're looking for that you think singles this situation out?

Comment: Ordinarily I agree with the decision of other community users to close a question of mine. However the question I asked *was specific* and is not addressed in the question you all say I am duplicating. Virus & malware mitigation is a huge topic, and I doubt that one single question covers all the bases. I feel like you all just see the word "virus" and automatically close my questions without actually *reading* them. I am not asking "how do I remove a virus" here, I am asking for a safe way to delete a specific EXE without it being hooked & executed. Two very different things. Disappointed.

Comment: I feel that, as asked, these questions are similar enough to be considered duplicates.  That's why I made the first comment - to make sure we're not missing something.  You should really not be trying this approach, IMO - the advice in that other question is good and solid.  More to the point, if this is a work machine, *it should really just be reimaged anyway* as a precaution.  FWIW and FYI for you, though, virus removal is a bit of a special circumstance on Super User - we are fairly aggressive closing virus questions that aren't very specialized to prevent a flood of nearly-identical ones.

Comment: Perhaps to give a metaphor - trying to individually delete exes when you have a malware infection is often like you're trying to put in screws with a hammer.  It might work, but it's ugly and it very rarely holds up as intended.

Comment: Well I guess that ends all sensible discussion.

Comment: I'm sorry that my attempt at being helpful was unsuccessful.